# Combinations in Racket only in one direction

Tags: scheme, racket

Following command produces combinations from a list but only in forward direction:

```
(combinations '(0 0 1 1) 2)
'((0 0) (0 1) (0 1) (0 1) (0 1) (1 1))
```

It does not produce combination (1 0).

Similarly:

```
(combinations '(0 0 1 1) 3)
'((0 0 1) (0 0 1) (0 1 1) (0 1 1))
```

It does not produce (1 0 0) (1 0 1) etc.

How can I make this command output all possible combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the very [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) (emphasis mine):

> "... a combination is a way of selecting items from a collection, such that (unlike permutations) **the order of selection does not matter**."

In other words `(0 1)` and `(1 0)` are equivalent, and the `combinations` procedure is *already* listing all possible combinations for the given input. Perhaps you're interested in the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of some lists?

```
(cartesian-product '(0 1) '(0 1))
=> '((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))

(cartesian-product '(0 1) '(0 1) '(0 1))
=> '((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had checked combinations and permutations but not cartesian-product.